# Save ImageGrid without ploting it on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am using following function to save ImageGrid, but i dont want to show it on jupyter notebook. How can i do that?

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
def save_img(hists,path):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
    grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,  # similar to subplot(111)
                     nrows_ncols=(16, 4),  # creates 2x2 grid of axes
                     axes_pad=0.1,  # pad between axes in inch.
                     )

    for ax, im in zip(grid, hists):
        # Iterating over the grid returns the Axes.
        ax.set_xticks([]),ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.margins(x=0,y=0)
        ax.imshow(im)
    plt.savefig(f'{path}.jpg',bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to save images, switch the matplotlib backend to
a non-gui backend like `Agg`! (see https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html)

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg") 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, ax = plt.subplots()
...
f.savefig(...)
```